# Best practise to hide related entity in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I have two entities called 'Member' and 'Role'. At the same page as I show the data of the 'Member' entity I would like to add a form for adding roles (one 'Role' per request) to this 'Member'.

Adding a new 'Role' entity includes the information of the related 'Member'. So the form must include a 'Member' entity to that `handleRequest($request)` works properly. What is the easiest way to hide this 'Member' entity in the form?

I have already googled a bit, but without satisfactorily results. I turned out following approaches:

1. using the symfony-generate-crud-default-settings:  and
    and hide them with css
2. using a hidden textfield with the ID
   of the member Data Transformers to transform the hidden textfield
   with a number back into a 'Member' entity

Option 1) looks more like a hack, while option 2) needs a lot of code for just a simple task. Is there no possibility to put the whole Member entity into a form component so that `handleRequest($request)` can handle the related entities properly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, Member and Role entities has ManyToMany association. In this case you should use '[collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)' form type.